# La fréquence d'emploi de « véto » est-elle comparable à celle des autres mots d'origine étrangère dont la graphie a été rectifiée par accentuation ?

Tags: lexique, diacritiques, emprunts, réforme-orthographique-1991

En politique américaine ou internationale<sup>1</sup>, on rapporte souvent le mot [**véto**](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/veto) et il ne fait aucun doute qu'il se prononce [\ve.to\](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/v%C3%A9to#Prononciation), qu'on l'écrive de manière traditionnelle, *veto*, ou sous sa graphie [rectifiée](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3168) ([1990](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifications_orthographiques_du_fran%C3%A7ais_en_1990)), *véto*. L'Académie française et l'OQLF, par exemple, voulant ménager le chèvre et le chou affirmeront « que ni les graphies traditionnelles, ni les nouvelles graphies proposées ne doivent être considérées comme fautives ». Et près de 30 ans plus tard un [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=droit%20de%20v%C3%A9to%2Cveto%2Cv%C3%A9to%2Cdroit%20de%20veto&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdroit%20de%20v%C3%A9to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cveto%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cv%C3%A9to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdroit%20de%20veto%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cdroit%20de%20v%C3%A9to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cveto%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cv%C3%A9to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdroit%20de%20veto%3B%2Cc0) montre que l'ancienne graphie s'impose toujours malgré un sursaut lors de la rectification possiblement dû au fait de présenter à l'écrit la nouvelle graphie. Par ailleurs on sait que [certains mots](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4351) de langue étrangère qui ne sont pas francisés ou dans certains cas des [locutions latines](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=courantes&btn_chercher=CHERCHER&id=3799) sont marqués de l'italique.

- Le ngram pour le mot *véto/veto* reflète-t-il adéquatement la situation ?
- Considérant une [liste](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3168) de graphies rectifiées par accentuation,
  peut-on généralement affirmer que la progression de leur emploi est
  similaire à celle qui semble être celle de *véto* ou doit-on nuancer ; peut-on même présenter un seul de ces mots dont la graphie rectifiée soit devenue plus courante que l'ancienne ?
- Pense-t-on que l'italique peut être utile pour différencier la
  graphie ancienne de la graphie moderne (par exemple, *veto* comme
  latinisme, véto en français moderne) ?
- Incidemment en ce qui a trait à véto, pense-t-on que la
  réduction/abréviation familière de [vétérinaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/v%C3%A9to#Nom_commun_1) (véto, véto.,
  véto') en français métropolitain nuit à l'adoption de la graphie
  rectifiée ?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Le contexte qui me fait réfléchir au mot est celui du recul navrant du droit des femmes à disposer librement de leur corps, que ce soit aux États-Unis ou en contexte de [guerre](https://www.lapresse.ca/international/europe/201904/23/01-5223218-violences-sexuelles-la-france-denonce-une-menace-de-veto-americain.php) ou de lutte à la [pauvreté](https://www.lapresse.ca/actualites/201904/22/01-5223018-des-eveques-bloquent-laide-a-des-ong-qui-tolerent-la-contraception.php). Des segments institutionnels d'une chrétienté surannée bloquent des fonds destinés aux femmes et on voit maintenant certaines superpuissances fascistes/communistes encourager ce recul par l'emploi de leur droit de véto au sein même d'institutions dont la mission est centrée sur la dignité humaine et pour lesquelles ils affichent de plus en plus par leurs paroles ou leurs gestes un mépris des plus total.</sub>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

J’ai choisi quelques termes parmi ceux [proposés par l’Office Québécois de la langue française](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3168) et ai décidé de comparer non les fréquences absolues d’emploi, mais plutôt les fréquences relatives de la nouvelle orthographe dans le temps, en fonction de la fréquence des deux orthographes. Selon la formule mathématique suivante, donc :

- accent / (traditionnel + accent)

Pour le test, j’ai choisi les termes suivants, un peu par goût personnel, un peu par popularité pressentie du terme dans l’usage habituel, un peu par curiosité pour certains termes inattendus :

- véto
- à priori
- à capella
- artéfact
- facsimilé
- kébab
- sombréro
- spéculum

Voici les résultats :

[image]

[Surprenamment](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bhvf/surprenamment), la grande majorité de ces termes semblent avoir eu un sommet de popularité pour la version accentuée dans la première moitié du XX<sup>e</sup> siècle.

- ***artéfact, facsimilé*** et ***spéculum*** dans les années 1910
- ***kébab*** à divers moments entre 1900 et 1939 environ
- ***à capella*** dans les années 1920
- ***à priori*** dans les années 1940, avec un long plateau s’étendant de 1933 à 1958

***Sombréro*** est apparemment inusité, et je l’avais ajouté par curiosité, l’orthographe rectifiée m’ayant semblé un très mauvais choix qui ne respectait pas la prononciation que j’utilise systématiquement et la seule que j’entends dans mon entourage, soit /sɔmbʁɛʁo/ *some-brè-ro,* et non /sɔmbʁeʁo/ *some-bré-ro.* Il semble que la Francophonie ait eu la même réaction que moi.

Quant à ***véto,*** il semble avoir connu son apogée plus tard, dans la fin des années 1980, et contrairement à l’hypothèse voulant que les rectifications de décembre 1990 aient été à la source d’un regain, il semble plutôt qu’elles en aient sonné le glas.

[image]

---

### Tendances et présences de l’accent

#### Fasimilé et spéculum

Parmi les huit cas, on constate que seuls ***facsimilé*** et ***spéculum*** étaient majoritairement accentués en 2008.

***Facsimilé*** a été relativement stable depuis 1900 *(l’ensemble de la période considérée ici)*, la version accentuée dominant pour l’ensemble de la période à l’exception de quatre années (1952-53, 1964, 1974) pour lesquelles ***facsimile*** fut très faiblement plus présent.

Si l’on considère la très possible transformation du son *é* en un *e muet* à cause de sa position en finale, on pourra comprendre que l’accentuation ait été ici assez majoritairement pressentie comme utile, et que l’on ait pas attendu le sceau d’approbation de l’Académie ou d’autres institutions linguistiques socialement respectées pour l’introduire.

***Spéculum***, après une descente commençant en 1974 et aboutissant à une période creuse de 1988 à 1993 *(36% d’accentuation malgré tout)*, soit étonamment les quelques années avant et après les rectifications orthographiques, a recommencé à gagner du terrain par la suite. L’accentuation était redevenue majoritaire en 2000, et a continué sur une lancée qui lui assure le sommet du classement parmi les huit termes de l’échantillon pour 2008, avec 63%.

#### Artéfact, kébab, à priori, à capella, véto

Dans ce groupe, seul ***kébab*** a été majoritaire en quelque moment que ce soit depuis 1900. Mais ça commence à dater : alors que de longues périodes l’indiquent dominant dans la première moitié du XX<sup>e</sup> siècle, ce ne fut plus le cas depuis 1953, et malgré un faible regain dans les années ’70, l’accent fut de plus en plus mis de côté, au point que 2008 le montre à son plus bas niveau depuis 1900, avec 5%. En dépit de ce creux, on sera peut-être surpris de le trouver encore alors au deuxième rang du groupe quant à l’accentuation.

Si on compare maintenant la présence en 2008 à celle des quelques années précédant les rectifications orthographiques, on découvre une autre curiosité : à l’exception d’***artéfact*** et dans une moindre mesure d’***à capella***, tous sont moins accentués en 2008 qu’ils ne l’étaient en 1990-91, et même les deux cas en légère remontée ont dû passer par un creux dans les années ’90.

En fait, tout semble indiquer que les rectifications orthographiques de 1990, [controversées et vigoureusement critiquées](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifications_orthographiques_du_fran%C3%A7ais_en_1990#Oppositions), avec un taux d’opposition atteignant encore 82% dans la population française selon un sondage tenu en février 2016, ces rectifications disais-je, loin de faire la promotion de l’accentuation, ont plutôt informé à plus grande échelle la population francophone que ces mots ne comportaient traditionnellement pas d’accents et qu’on acceptait désormais officiellement qu’ils en aient. Dans la foulée du rejet de la nouvelle orthographe, on en serait peut-être venu à modifier même son propre usage personnel afin de la conformer aux règles qui avaient cours avant **(les bonnes règles)**, plutôt qu’aux nouvelles règles **(les méchantes règles)**. C’est sûrement un peu simplificateur, mais ça explique sûrement une partie de la situation.

En effet, pour tester mon hypothèse, je me suis penché sur des changements d’accents établis par les rectifications de 1990. Si l’on songe aujourd’hui à l’orthographe ***évènement***, elle me semble bien peu sujet à des prises de positions fortes la décriant. Elle correspond bien mieux à la prononciation du terme que le plus classique ***événement***. La théorie du rejet en bloc pourrait être renforcée si l’on observe qu’une modification aussi mineure et naturelle que celle qui donne une pichenette vers la gauche au second accent d’événement a aussi subi une descente et demeure encore controversée en 2008. J’ai ajouté ***règlementaire*** à la recherche pour un deuxième avis. Je laisse au lectorat le soin de voir pour eux-même leur position et celle qu’il présume à la population en général, mais je mentionne que le résultat m’a surpris : quand j’ai songé à ce test, je m’attendais à ce qu’il démolisse mon hypothèse. Et ce ne fut pas le cas.

[image]

Force est d’admettre que 1991 est une année charnière sur l’ensemble de ces courbes : elle marque le début d’un déclin qui continuera pendant près d’une décennie. Et même si une graphie comme *évènement* semble remonter la pente, on est encore loin de la coupe aux lèvres avec le maigre trois et des poussières pourcent d’utilisation de la nouvelle accentuation, pour naturelle qu’elle puisse objectivement sembler.

#### Sombréro

Oui bon... Pas [grand’chose](https://www.grevisse.fr/le-blog-chroniques-grevisse/histoire-de-la-typographie/trait-d-union-ou-apostrophe-grand-mere-qu-t) à en dire.

---

#### Conclusion

Un phénomène de rejet des rectifications semble bien avoir eu lieu. À tort ou à raison *(plutôt à tort selon moi, mais mon opinion importe peu),* la correspondance prononciation-orthographe semble de peu d’impact par rapport au respect dû aux graphies *« traditionnelles »*, qui ne sont d’ailleurs traditionnelles que dans une acception particulièrement peu contraignante du terme. On a qu’à visiter les éditions originales des pièces de théâtre du XVII<sup>e</sup> siècle pour s’en convaincre. Par exemple [Horace](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k72709x/f13.double) de Corneille dans une édition de 1641, où l’on peut lire des termes fort éloignés de l’orthographe traditionnelle défendue contre les réformes de 1990, tels que ***succés*** pour ***succès***, ***conceués*** pour ***concevez***, ***veux*** pour ***vœux***, ***ie*** pour ***je*** ou ***perils*** pour ***périls***.

Expliquer le rejet, par contre, est une autre paire de manches. Est-ce que les rectifications auraient eu l’effet de renforcer la connaissance et l’intérêt de l’étymologie dans le grand public ? Est-ce que ces connaissances nouvellement acquises auraient provoqué un élan de fierté poussant à exprimer son respect pour les graphies étrangères, même lorsqu’un terme a pourtant bien intérgré la langue courante ? Est-ce qu’une volonté d’authenticité et de respect, ou une autre forme moins avouable de snobisme ou de pédantisme, a conduit les gens à priser, peut-être même démesurément, les formes originales aux détriments de formes plus cohérentes dans le système orthographique français ?

Compte tenu de l’indéniable importance historique de l’étymologie dans l’établissement de l’orthographe française *(les exemples sont innombrables ; on pourra penser à doi**g**t, poi**d**s,  tem**p**s ou nombri**l**)*, on pourrait le croire, au moins en partie.

Les faibles performances de l’accentuation d’expressions latines en deux mots (***à priori, à capella***, mais aussi ***à posteriori/postériori***), en déclin déjà depuis plus de 30 ans en 1990 et en descente aussi depuis, tendraient à renforcer l’hypothèse d’un respect de l’étymologie, tout au moins quand il s’agit de latin.

[image]

Ce n’est néanmoins qu’une partie de la réponse. Une graphie comme ***nénufar***, proposée en 1990 parce qu’on la dit alors [étymologiquement plus exacte](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%A9nuphar#Orthographe) que celle de ***nénuphar*** qui était la seule officielle depuis 1935, subit elle aussi un recul après 1994. Elle n’a, depuis 1900, que quelques fois dépassé la barre des 10% d’utilisation, et jamais depuis 1994. Un amour nouveau pour l’étymologie et la tradition ne suffit donc pas à expliquer seul le rejet des rectifications.

[image]

Le cas de ***facsimilé,*** qui a traversé la crise sans un soubresaut, nous montre peut-être un cas où l’usage s’est auto-régulé, sans qu’une quelconque prise de position officielle, fut-elle très défavorablement reçue dans son ensemble, puisse y changer quoi que ce soit. Le mouvement de fond qui voulait expliciter le son final, naturel et librement consenti par les usagers, pourrait ici s’être révélé bien plus important que la forte aversion pour les rectifications de 1990.

Pour la nouvelle jeunesse que s’offre la graphie ***artéfact,*** je serais tenté d’y voir un signe que la finale ne marque pas d’emblée le terme comme étant étranger, mais ça reste à confirmer. Des termes courants comme ***exact, impact, intact*** ou ***tact*** pourraient aider à défendre le point de vue, mais avec seulement [13 mots en langue française](https://www.listesdemots.net/f/a/3/motsfinissantact.htm) se terminant par *ACT*, ce n’est pas entièrement convaincant.

Les mots se terminant par *BAB*, comme *kébab*, sont plus clairement [exotiques](https://www.listesdemots.net/f/b/3/motsfinissantbab.htm) : ***baobab, kebab, nabab, rabab, rebab*** et ***toubab***.

Quant à ceux se terminant en *O*, comme *véto* et *sombrero*, bien que très fréquents en français *(plusieurs par apocope : **alcoolo, clodo, dico, hélico, nitro,** etc. ; certains aujourd’hui assez ressentis comme français : **auto, moto** ; quelques-uns de plein droit : **bobo, allo**),* beaucoup sont très communément sentis, à juste titre d’ailleurs, comme d’origine latine *(dont **veto**, qui nous intéresse particulièrement ici, mais aussi **placebo**, dont le statut fut lui aussi modifié en 1990)*, espagnole *(**gaucho, macho, pueblo, sombrero, tango**)* ou italienne *(**adagio, allegro, incognito, falsetto, libretto,** etc.)*. Est-ce qu’une propension à conserver latin le latin aura joué contre l’accentuation de ***veto*** ? Peut-être...

Par simple curiosité **à postériori**, j’ai fait deux nouvelles requêtes nGrams sur ***placébo***, l’une commençant en 1900, l’autre en 1950 pour mieux montrer le détail de la période récente.

[image]

[image]

Comment: L'idée d'authenticité peut-être aussi avec la nourriture, ça me rappelle l'histoire du [spaghetti](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=1030) déjà au pluriel etc. mais qui dit _raviolo_ au singulier en français, mais la question de l'accentuation est différente un peu de celle des pluriels. Parmi les termes choisis, a-t-on quelque chose de particulier à dire si on se concentre sur ceux qui n'auraient qu'une seule prononciation soit celle uniquement représentée par le diacritique, comme _véto_ ?

Comment: Merci pour le terme *authenticité*, qui m'a échappé lors de la composition et qui trouvera la place qui lui revient dans le dernier paragraphe. Quant à la discussion concernant les autres mots, je dois y réfléchir et chercher un peu; ça m'évitera d'étaler des bêtises.

Comment: Très bonne idée de faire `mot1/(mot1 + mot2)`, je n'y avais jamais pensé !

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Merci du commentaire. J'ai par ailleurs procédé à plusieurs révisions qui m’ont apporté quelques surprises, si vous êtes intéressé.

Comment: @Montéedelait Je suis intéressé :)

Comment: Absolument excellent. Merci !

Answer (score 0):

Tout d'abord, j'aimerais revenir sur un point:

> "Et près de 30 ans plus tard un ngram montre que l'ancienne graphie
>   s'impose toujours malgré un sursaut lors de la rectification
>   possiblement dû au fait de présenter à l'écrit la nouvelle graphie."

L'Étymologie du mot « veto » vient du latin veto (« j’interdis »). Il est employé (Par extension) pour exprimer une opposition catégorique.

Les **rectifications orthographiques du français en 1990** recommandent une nouvelle orthographe pour certains mots du français afin de la rendre plus simple ou d'en supprimer certaines incohérences. Elles ont pour origine un rapport du Conseil supérieur français de la langue française, publié dans les Documents administratifs du Journal officiel de la République française du 6 décembre 1990.

Elles ont pour objectif de rectifier l’orthographe de certains mots, ***sans pour autant être une réforme***. Elles veulent notamment permettre de lever l’ambigüité de la signification ou de la prononciation de certains mots.

Lors de ces dernière, ils a été décidé que le mot « véto » devraient dorénavant s'écrire **« veto »**.

*« véto » pouvant également être utilisé en tant qu'abréviation familière pour un vétérinaire (véto’ pour un respect formel de la typographie d’une abréviation familière).*

Le [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=droit%20de%20v%C3%A9to%2Cveto%2Cv%C3%A9to%2Cdroit%20de%20veto&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdroit%20de%20v%C3%A9to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cveto%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cv%C3%A9to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdroit%20de%20veto%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cdroit%20de%20v%C3%A9to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cveto%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cv%C3%A9to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdroit%20de%20veto%3B%2Cc0) suivant me parraît donc être parfaitement cohérent:

[image: ngram]

---

Sources:

- [Annexe:Rectifications orthographiques du français en 1990](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Annexe:Rectifications_orthographiques_du_fran%C3%A7ais_en_1990)
- [Rectifications orthographiques du français en 1990](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifications_orthographiques_du_fran%C3%A7ais_en_1990)
- [veto - Wictionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/veto)
- [Véto - Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/V%C3%A9to)
- [Google Ngram Viewer: droit de véto,veto,véto,droit de veto](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=droit%20de%20v%C3%A9to%2Cveto%2Cv%C3%A9to%2Cdroit%20de%20veto&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdroit%20de%20v%C3%A9to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cveto%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cv%C3%A9to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdroit%20de%20veto%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cdroit%20de%20v%C3%A9to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cveto%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cv%C3%A9to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdroit%20de%20veto%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: « Lors de ces dernière, ils a été décidé que le mot « véto » devraient dorénavant s'écrire « veto ». ». Ce serait plutôt l'inverse... Une révision de l'orthographe du texte s’imposerait soit dit en passant. Aussi peut-être expliquer pourquoi on trouve le ngram « cohérent », je ne vois pas le lien exact entre ce qu'on dit précédemment et cette affirmation...

Comment: Cela doit être une erreur de ma part, je vais donc supprimer la réponse

Comment: Il n'est pas nécessaire de supprimer la réponse. Il suffit de corriger et d'expliquer davantage son point de vue.